# why does my destructor code execute on instantiation and what is it really doing?

Tags: c++

If I place breakpoints in my destructor I notice that all the code is run through when I instantiate said object, but the lines don't have any effect (as in, the delete does not actually seem to delete the object) What is really going on here?

I am using visual studio, is this an artifact (is that the right word?) of the program?

destructor being called:

```
Brain::~Brain()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < weapons.size(); i++)
    {
         delete weapons[i];
    }
}
```

if I place breakpoints in here, they get triggered when the Brain is instantiated! and again when I close the program.

here is the objects constructor:

```
Brain::Brain(
int health,
Level& level,
vector<Agent>& agents,
//vector<Pickup>& pickups,
D3DXCOLOR colour,
Mesh& mesh)
: Entity(colour, mesh), gunOffset(D3DXVECTOR3(0, 0, 1.0f)), 

level(level),
agents(agents),
//pickups(pickups),
colour(colour),
health(health),

enemies(vector<int>()),
seenEnemies(vector<int>()),
seenPickups(vector<int>()),

seenEnemyMarkers(vector<BoundingSphere>()),
seenPickupMarkers(vector<BoundingSphere>()),
weapons(vector<Gun*>()),
RoomKills(vector<int>()),
pathVisualisation(vector<Edge>()),
search(vector<int>()),

WALKING_INCREMENT(0.06f),
TOLERANCE(0.1f),
COMBAT_SEARCH_TIME(0),
SHOTGUN_STOPPING_DISTANCE(1.5f), PISTOL_STOPPING_DISTANCE(5.0f),
SPAWNTIME(120),
IMPACT_DISTANCE(0.6f),
FIELD_OF_VIEW(0.95f),
MARKER_SIZE(0.5f)
{
currentNodeInSearchPathInt = 0;
combatSearchCycle = 0;
spawnCycle = 0;
globalNodePositionIndex = 0;
//fightOrFlight = 0;

 chosenTarget = -1;
 previousTarget = -1;
 pickupMemory = -1;
 agentMemory = -1;



for (unsigned int i = 0; i < level.RoomCentreNodeVectors().size(); i++)
{
    RoomKills.push_back(level.Nodes()[level.RoomCentreNodeVectors()[i][0]].Room());
}

weapons.push_back(new Pistol());
weapons.push_back(new Rifle());
weapons.push_back(new Shotgun());

prevTargetType = AGENT;
targetType = AGENT;
currentWeapon = PISTOL;

state = SPAWN;
}
```

could it have something to do with this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
agents.push_back(Agent(100, *level, agents/*, level->Pickups()*/, D3DXCOLOR(1.0F, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f), *mesh));
}
```

Agent inherits from Brain.

This is Agent:

```
#ifndef AGENT_H
#define AGENT_H

#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include "Brain.h"

class level;

class Agent : public Brain
{
private:
    int counter;
    Level& level;

int previousState;

const int
    TARGET_IS_AGENT,
    TARGET_IS_OBJECT,
    TARGET_IS_AGENT_MEMORY,
    NO_TARGET;

int fightFlightThreshold;

const int SHOTGUN_DISTANCE_TOLERANCE;
public:
Agent(int health,
    Level& level,
    vector<Agent>& agents,
    D3DXCOLOR colour,
    Mesh& mesh);
void UpdateAgent();
void DrawAgent(D3DXMATRIX matView, D3DXMATRIX matProjection, bool dataVis);
void RegenerativeHealth();
//int TargetChooser();
};

#endif
```

Comment: What do you mean, they don't have effect? They're not actually being executed?

Comment: try rebuilding your project and debug again

Comment: I don't understand your question. Destructors are executed when an instance is destroyed (either by `delete` or by getting out of scope). Good practice is to have small destructors, only releasing resources...

Comment: if you are running in Visual Studio, are you running it in Debug or Release mode? Sometimes the instruction pointer jumps around a bit in Release mode

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that's why this surprised me

Comment: Show us the instantiation code, both the constructor and the creation of the object.

Comment: try debug mode and see if the problem exists there as well

Comment: also, why has this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

Destructors for the object being instantiated should *not* be executed during that instantiation.

However, it *may* be that temorary objects are created as part of the process. That's the only thing I can think of that makes sense based on your description that the code is running (for the temporary objects) but not having an effect (on the object being instantiated).

This may not be too hard to check. Examint the `this` pointer when you're sitting at a breakpoint in the destructor then compare that with the object pointer after instantiation.

If they're the same, I'd be *very* surprised.

Comment: The Brain pointer, assuming that's the thing being instantiated and the thing you state the destructor is being called for.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't compare it to the object after instantiation because the code breaks at this point.

Comment: Breaks as in breakpoint? Then just record `this` in the destructor and single-step or step-out-of until the instantiation is finished. Then compare the values.

Comment: @SirYakalot if you are getting runtime errors I strongly suggest that you start commenting out one line of code at a time and try to pinpoint the instruction that is causing the access violation warning

Comment: @Default it happens on the line that says delete weapons[i] either when I close the program if the loop that instatiates agents is set to loop once, or at the start of the program if I am instantiating more than one agent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your compiled binary isn't up to date with your source code and debugger shows wrong line to be executed. This happens sometimes in Visual Studio.

Comment: By rebuilding your project and debugging again.

Comment: Which object owns the Brain-object? How it is assigned to target object?

Comment: This is little suspicious: level(level),
agents(agents),
//pickups(pickups),
colour(colour),
health(health), Your member variables have same names as constructor  parameters.

Comment: And how is the agents member variable defined?

Answer (score 0):

If you put a breakpoint in the destructor and then look at the call stack, you will see the line that is causing the destructor to run. Almost certainly there is some copying going on and a temporary is being destructed, which is confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging in release mode is sometimes tricky. The default optimization may optimize out some code so what you're stepping into in Dev studio may not match what is actually executing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are [Debugging optimized code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/606cbtzs%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> When the compiler optimizes code, it repositions and reorganizes
>   instructions, resulting in more efficient compiled code. Because of
>   this rearrangement, the debugger cannot always identify the source
>   code that corresponds to a set of instructions.
>
> Optimization can affect:
>
> - Local variables, which can be removed by the optimizer or moved to
>     locations the debugger does not understand.
> - Positions inside a function, which are changed when the optimizer
>     merges blocks of code.
> - Function names for frames on the call stack, which may be wrong if the
>     optimizer merges two functions.

So it could be that the debugger shows the instruction that it *thinks* is the next instruction, but actually isn't